# What is the main difference between float4 and half4 in fragment shader function?

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit

I try to set render pipeline and MTKView color attachment pixel format of MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float.

However, it seem same with MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB.

I just want to make the render color range higher(HDR).

Is the return type of the fragment function important?

What should I set to realize a high dynamic range in metal ?

Comment: Are you actually producing color values outside the [0, 1] range? Are you applying any kind of tone-mapping process? It sounds like you've succeeded in creating an HDR rendering target, but are you doing any HDR drawing?

Comment: Yes. I use a MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float and MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB format texture to store some color values outside [0,1] in one render pass. After that, I use some simple tone-mapping algorithm to map it inside [0,1] in another render pass.

Comment: Is that HDR mean the color can store outside [0,1] range in the middle render pass and map inside [0,1] range in the last render pass? Thanks for your help. @warrenm

Comment: That's an important part of it, yes. Using higher-precision intermediate targets is what enables things like bloom, depth-of-field, etc., which are often considered to be big components of the HDR "look."

Comment: By the way, use `half4` as your fragment function return type when possible, especially on mobile.

Comment: @warrenm Does using `half4 fragment my_fragment_function()` instead of `float4` save memory?

Comment: It mostly saves bandwidth. If you're rendering to a texture whose components are 8 or 16 bits, using `half` as the return component type reduces bandwidth and power use with no loss in quality.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

**float:**

> A 32-bit floating-point. The float data type must conform to the IEEE
>   754 single precision storage format.

Full **float** precision is generally used for world space positions, texture coordinates, or scalar computations involving complex functions such as trigonometry or power/exponentiation.

**half:**

> A 16-bit floating-point. The half data type must conform to the IEEE
>   754 binary16 storage format.

**Half** precision is useful for short vectors, directions, object space positions, high dynamic range colors.